# How do I route SSH traffic to my VPS that is connected to a VPN?

Tags: vpn, routing, vps

So I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours now and im starting to get frustrated.  I have a VPS that I log into through SSH.  I am connecting to my VPN service (nordvpn) from that VPS.  In a perfect world I would be able to use the nordvpn app to connect to their VPN service instead of using openvpn because the nord app has a few features that make things easier (random switching of their servers, selecting country by typing its name, etc).  When I attempt to connect to nordvpn through their app I am immediately disconnected from my ssh connection.  I have to then log into my VPS through its web console provided by the service provider to turn the nordvpn connection off if I want to be able to SSH back in from my machine.  How can I set this up so that I can use their VPN in this way?  Heres some info that might help.

First this is output of "ifconig" on my vps:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet x.x.x.x  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast x.x.n.m
    inet6 <removed>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether ba:34:82:44:0f:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1469133  bytes 4209036445 (3.9 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1007911  bytes 268157669 (255.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet y.y.y.y  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast y.y.255.255
    ether ba:34:82:44:0f:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet z.z.z.z  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast z.z.255.255
    inet6 <removed>  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether aa:93:20:c4:94:60  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 326  bytes 16840 (16.4 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 186  bytes 15120 (14.7 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 2666023  bytes 1403474636 (1.3 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 2666023  bytes 1403474636 (1.3 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and when i connect to the VPN app it adds a tun0 interface whos ip is not static:

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.8.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.1.3
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 14  bytes 5417 (5.2 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 23  bytes 2019 (1.9 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ip tables are completely flushed when not connected to vpn and when i use the nordvpn app it adds a ton of stuff.  Here is the output of "iptables -L" when connected to VPN:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  66.171.37.83         anywhere             ctstate
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  loopback/8           anywhere             ctstate 
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  66.171.37.83         anywhere             ctstate
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  134.209.32.0/20      anywhere             ctstate  
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  66.171.37.83         anywhere             ctstate 
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.17.0.0/16         anywhere             ctstate 
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  66.171.37.83         anywhere             ctstate 
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.132.0.0/16        anywhere             ctstate 
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  66.171.37.83         anywhere             ctstate 
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere             ctstate
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             103.86.96.100        udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             103.86.99.100        udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             103.86.96.100        udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             103.86.99.100        udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             66.171.37.83        
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8          
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             66.171.37.83        
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             134.209.32.0/20     
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             66.171.37.83        
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.17.0.0/16        
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             66.171.37.83        
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.132.0.0/16       
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             66.171.37.83        
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.8.0.0/24         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I have been reading on the subject for quite a while now and from what i can tell I need to probably mark and forward packets on port 22 somewhere but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like NordVPN is blocking ssh port. As i was reading about Nord VPN all traffic go via their node. login to your profile at Nordvpn and check if u can allow from their.